What did Selphie mean exactly by saying "Like I'm really going to!"?
In Final Fantasy VIII, there's this dialogue:

Selphie: Wow, this lift is pretty cool!
Zell: Don't get too excited, or you'll fall!
Selphie: Like I'm really going to!

What did Selphie mean exactly by "Like I'm really going to!"?

What is the context? Are they walking along on top of a tall wall? Running?

They are on a kind of elevator lifter.

This question would be better suited to English Language Learners.

Is there a compelling reason to suppose it's not just regular sarcasm?

@jwodder:
We take language questions regarding SFF works.

If it is sarcasm ,she would fall from the lifter becouse he’s to anoing  or something like that ?Or iis it becouse she wouldn’t fall so easily?

Because she wouldn't fall so easily. You could compare it to a kid walking along a bench. The parent says, "Watch out, or you'll fall!" and the kid says, "Like I would fall..." because they are certain that they would not.

Selphie is likely simply being sarcastic, using "like" in two different contexts.

—used interjectionally in informal speech often to emphasize a word or phrase (as in "He was, like, gorgeous") or for an apologetic, vague, or unassertive effect (as in "I need to, like, borrow some money")


as if

In other words, she is not going to fall, so she's saying "As if I would fall", and pronunciation of the "like" as more separate (something I would assume here, although I don't think the characters are voiced in this game except maybe during cutscenes) adds to the sarcasm.
